# Error while posting form in laravel (CORS)

Tags: laravel

I have installed Laravel 7.0 and working with angular 12 as a frontend. I used this package

> https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

This is my kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
       
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        
    ];
}
```

> cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => ['*'],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/contact-us', [SiteController::class, 'contactUs']);
});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['api'],
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'Profile']);  
  
});
```

I'm getting this error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Answer (score 0):

#### Testing with own CORS middleware

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The website handling the request (here `localhost:4200`) must set this header to allow requests cross-origin. So the package doesn't do anything, apparently.
I cannot help with the package used, but here is how to set the headers with your own middleware (may help others). Change the headers as you see fit. We'll use this for testing:

**`app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    return $next($request)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH');
  }
}
```

In `app/Http/Kernel.php` we add it to `$middleware`:

```php
    protected $middleware = [
        // ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, 
    ];
```

The server should now set the respective headers.
This might not be your solution, but you can at least debug what is different.

Documentation for `Access-Control-Allow-...`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have implemented this custom middleware but sometimes the user complains that they cannot access site due to cors issue, do cors middleware fail in some scenario like location from which the site is accessed or time

Comment: Okay, sure. Depending on the exact request and response some requests might still lead to be rejected. If this generally works, then you must debug these concrete requests. It should not be the fault of the middleware directly. Rejected requests include ones where body/headers/method was not set correctly, so there is a lot that can go wrong between computer and keyboard on their end.

Comment: same register form on one system is working and on the other gets fails due to cors error

Comment: Okay that still depends on the concrete request, including headers. You have an example that works, so nothing easier than finding the difference.. right?

Comment: Thanks i will check both request

Comment: Is it compulsory to pass header in front end application (Angular)

Comment: The headers `Access-Control-Allow-...` are always from the perspective of the server, not the client/front-end. Otherwise the client could just change it and subvert the reason cors headers exist.